# VS Code devcontainers - what is the difference between remoteUser and containerUser?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-container-tools

Reading the devcontainer.json reference, I still can't understand:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference

```
containerUser: Overrides the user all operations run as inside the container.
remoteUser: Overrides the user that VS Code runs as in the container (along with sub-processes like terminals, tasks, or debugging)
```

What is the difference between `containerUser` and `remoteUser`? When should I use one or the other? Can you provide examples?

Thanks!

Comment: I am asking a similar question to clarify containerUser and User in Dockerfile. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70759283/vs-code-devcontainer-what-is-the-difference-between-containeruser-and-user-in

Answer (score 1):

From the [definition of the devcontainer.json schema](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_schema/)

```json
{
    "remoteUser": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "The username to use for spawning processes in the container including lifecycle scripts and any remote editor/IDE server process. The default is the same user as the container."
    },
    "containerUser": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "The user the container will be started with. The default is the user on the Docker image."
    }
}
```