# VS Code devcontainer - what is the difference between containerUser and USER in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

From the [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference)

> containerUser: Overrides the user for all operations run as inside the
> container. Defaults to either root or the last USER instruction in the
> related Dockerfile used to create the image.

Does it mean that when you set up `containerUser` below in `devcontainer.json`

```json
"containerUser": "user-name"
```

Just same as `USER` in `Dockerfile` as below??

```
USER user-name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [definition of devcontainer.json schema](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_schema/)

```json
{
  "containerUser": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "The user the container will be started with. The default is the user on the Docker image."
  },
}
```

So, `containerUser` is the same as the `User on the Docker Image`.